# Uniqueness of metric from compact simple group of isometries

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

Let $ G_1,G_2 $ be compact simple groups acting transitively and isometrically on a manifold $ M $. So
$$
G_1/H_1 \cong M \cong G_2/H_2
$$
Equip $ G_1 $ with the unique bi-invariant metric. Equip $ G_1/H_1 $ with the pushforward of this metric onto $ G_1/H_1 $, call this metric $ g_1 $.

Similarly, equip $ G_2 $ with the unique bi-invariant metric. Equip $ G_2/H_2 $ with the pushforward of this metric onto $ G_2/H_2 $, call this metric $ g_2 $.

Is $ (G_1/H_1,g_1) $ always isometric to $ (G_2/H_2,g_2) $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a very small point:  bi-invariant metrics on simple Lie groups are only unique up to scaling.  Thus, one should ask whether $(G_1/H_1, g_1)$ is always isometric to some scaling of $(G_2/H_2, g_2)$.

The answer to this question is no, sometimes the metrics $g_1$ and $g_2$ are not isometric, even up to scaling.  Curiously, the only examples I know fitting all your criteria are spheres.  If you relax the first sentence to *not* require that both $G_1$ and $G_2$ act isometrically with respect to *some* Riemannian metric on $M$, then I can provide some more examples.

Consider $M = S^{2n+1}$ with $n\geq 2$, equipped with its canonical round metric (scaled however you wish).  Then both $G_1 = SO(2n+2)$ and $G_2 = SU(n+1)$ act transitively and preserve this metric.  The isotropy groups are $H_1 = SO(2n+1)$ and $H_2 = SU(n)$.  The isotropy action of $H_1$ is irreducible, so there is a unique (up to scaling) unique metric on $G_1/H_1$ which is invariant under the $G_1$ action.  Since we already know the round metric is one example, it follows that the induced metric on $G_1/H_1$ is the round metric.

On the other hand, the isotropy action of $H_2$ is not irreducible; since $n\geq 2$ it splits into a sum of the a $1$-dimensional trivial rep together with the (irreducible) standard rep of $H_2$.  Thus, up to scaling, there is a one parameter family of metrics on $G_2/H_2$ which are preserved by the $G_2$ action.  This one parameter family of course includes the round metric, but it more general contains Berger metrics where the metric is scaled only in the direction of the fibers of the Hopf map.

It turns out that for $n\geq 2$, the metric induced on $G_2/H_2$ is *not* round, but is, instead, one of these Berger metrics.  I don't know where one can find this calculation in the literature, but it is not so bad.  Specifically, there are good formulas for computing curvature on homogeneous spaces with metric induced from a bi-invariant metric, and these will show that $G_2/H_2$ does *not* have constant sectional curvature.

Comment: There are similar examples on $M = S^{4n+3}$, where one also has a transitive action by $Sp(n+1)$.  Thus, one obtains $3$ metrics on $M$, and no two are pairwise isometric, even up to scaling.  If you relax  the condition by not requiring that both $G_1$ and $G_2$ act isometrically with respect to most metrics, then one can add some other examples, like $SU(2) \times SU(2)/S^1$ for various (non-conjugate) embeddings of $S^1$ into $SU(2)\times SU(2)$.

Comment: I am curious about which Berger metrics arise this way

Comment: Weird so the natural metric on $ SU_4/Sp_2=SO_6/SO_5=S^5 $ is the round metric but the natural metric on $ SU_3/SU_2=S^5 $ is almost a round metric but its sort of distorted in one direction so its just a Berger metric.

Comment: Actual follow-up question: Does one of the metrics on $ M $ always have an isometry group of higher dimension? Or is it possible for $ (G_1/H_1,g_1) $ and $(G_2/H_2,g_2) $ to have isometry groups of the same dimension even though the metrics are different (i.e. not scalar multiplies)?

Comment: @Didier:  Here is an article which does the calculation for $SU(3)/SU(2) = S^5$ (at the end of the article):  https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/ims/bull51/M5102.pdf .  If you compare the formula for curvture derived in that article with the well-known (that I've forgotten!) values for the Berger sphere, you should be able to match them up.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  The only examples I know are spheres, where the isometry groups have different dimensions.

Comment: At first I thought you said (in your answer) that there is *only* a one parameter family of homogeneous of metrics on $S^3$. In fact there is a three parameters family ($\mu_1,\mu_2$ and $\mu_3$ in the article you linked). This confused me! Thank you for this reference by the way

Comment: @Didier:  Yes, perhaps I should clarify: in my answer, I specialized to the case of $S^{2n+1}$ with $n\geq 2$ to exclude $S^3$ for multiple reasons.  One is, as you noted, it has a larger family of homogeneous metrics.  In the context of my answer, this is because the isotropy group $H_2$ is trivial in this case, so the isotropy representation has even more irreducible pieces.  Another reason is because the bi-invariant metric on $SU(2)$ gives the round metric on $S^3$.  One easy way to see this is that with a bi-invariant metric, the isometry group contains (at least!)....

Comment: a copy of $SU(2)\times SU(2)/\pm(I,I)$, where the two factors from from left and right multiplication by $SU(2)$ and the $\pm(I,I)$ is simply noting that left multiplying by $-I$ and right multiplying by $-I$ gives the same isometry.  But if a $3$-manifold has isometry group of dimension $6$, it must have constant curvature (which can be seen by lifting the action to the orthogonal frame bundle), so it must be a round sphere if compact and simply connected.