# Two different maximum symmetry metrics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $ M $ be a compact connected manifold. The degree of symmetry of $ M $, denoted $ N(M) $, is the maximum of the dimensions of the isometry groups of all possible Riemannian structures on $ M $. See for example

https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-146-00/S0002-9947-1969-0250340-1/S0002-9947-1969-0250340-1.pdf

Does there exists a compact connected manifold $ M $ and two metrics $ g_1,g_2 $ such that
$$
dim(Iso(M,g_1))=N(M)=dim(Iso(M,g_2))
$$
but the isometry groups $ Iso(M,g_1) $ and $ Iso(M,g_2) $ are non isomorphic Lie groups?

I'm mostly interesting in the case that $ Iso(M,g_1) $ and $ Iso(M,g_2) $ are semisimple or even simple. I'm also mostly interested in the connected component of the identity. So examples like the flat metric on the hexagonal torus $ T^2 $ versus the square torus $ T^2 $ don't really concern me because the isometry groups agree on the identity component.

What I'm really looking for would be something like $ N(M)=21 $ and $ Iso(M,g_1)=Sp(3) $ while $ Iso(M,g_2)=Spin_7 $

This question

[Uniqueness of metric from compact simple group of isometries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555231/uniqueness-of-metric-from-compact-simple-group-of-isometries/4555916#4555916)

gives examples like round $ S^5=SO_6/SO_5 $ and Berger $ S^5=SU_3/SU_2 $. But the Berger sphere does not have an isometry group of maximum dimension $ dim(Iso(SU_3/SU_2))=8 \neq 15= dim(Iso(SU_3/SU_2)) = N(S^5) $